# CouchDB and PouchDB are producing duplicate records when recreating same CouchDB from scratch with a script

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb, couchdb-futon, couchdb-2.0, couchdb-mango

We have a couch DB we are developing on. We have a script that, for development purposes, just recreates the couch database from some json files from scratch every time we run that script. All the data we are inserting into couch from this script have unique _id's within all of the databases/documents.

The problem is, after we run this script, the pouch database in the browser starts creating duplicates when it synchronizes with couch. This results in duplicate data both in pouch and couch because when pouch replicates back to couch, couch will now contain duplicate data too.

Does anyone know if  there any way or method to prevent this duplication from occurring? It was my understanding the _id field was suppose to be unique, but that's clearly not the case, because both couch and pouch are creating duplicate records with the same _id fields.

Comment: can you add an example of a duplicate? It is correct that the database should not be willing to view 2 documents with the same id as distinct, rather the two documents created in different times/ways are likely to have different _revs and therefore be conflicting revisions of the same document.

Comment: I believe, as OP mentioned, it is related to `_id`